# Взаимодействия между проектами Python

Tags: python, linux

Ситуация такая, на сервере есть некоторое количество папок с проектами, все проекты одинаковы по коду и отличаются только файлом config.py. Проекты представляют из себя Telegram ботов запущенных через systemctl. В каждом проекте есть файл statistic.py, в котором реализован функционал для получение статистики из бд бота. Функция получения статистики возвращает значение типа `dict`. Так же в файле есть конструкция `if __name__ == "__main__"`, которая вызывает эту функцию внутри `print()`, это нужно для того чтоб я из консоли мог посмотреть статистику.

Мне нужно реализовать скрипт который проходился бы по каждому проекту, и суммировал их статистику в общую. Я хочу понять каким образом это можно сделать. Есть вариант через добавление из каждого проекта модуля statistic.py в `sys.path`, и в последствии вызова функции получения статистики, но я не уверен насколько это правильно.
Локальный сервер для каждого проекта поднимать не вариант, ибо количество проектов в обозримом будущем может перевалить за максимальное количество портов.

Я хотел бы понять через какие пути вообще возможно это сделать

Вся система работает на Linux Ubuntu.

Comment: "но я не уверен насколько это правильно." - а что именно тут может быть неправильно?

Comment: правильно было бы, наверное, чтобы каждый бот _сам_ отправлял свою статистику в какую-то общую базу.